# How to get/extract the symbolic meaning of integer values in a SNMP MIB file for every OID?

Tags: snmp, translate, mib

Some OIDs returns an integer value that is not a measure, instead it means a state or condition.
For instance, the MIB LIEBERT-GP-ENVIRONMENTAL-MIB has a lot of OIDS like this one:

```
lgpEnvConfigTempControlAlgorithm OBJECT-TYPE
SYNTAX      INTEGER 
{ 
    pi(1), 
    pid(2), 
    intelligent(3), 
    proportional(4) 
}
MAX-ACCESS  read-write
STATUS      current
DESCRIPTION
    "Selects the algorithm for controlling temperature."
::= { lgpEnvConfig 33 }
```

So, how to get all possibles values (in this case, 1->"pi" and 2->"pid", 3->"intelligent", 4->"proportional") for every OID ?
I've tried with snmptranslate but I got nothing on values (snmptranslate -Tz -M+/usr/share/snmp/mibs/Liebert/ -m LIEBERT-GP-ENVIRONMENTAL-MIB ).
A snmpget/walk in symbolic mode (-m all -M+whatever) returns only the current state (I mean "intelligent" if the current state of that feature is 3), but for others states, if not occurring, they are not showed, and I only know there is others states looking directly into the MIB file.

Comment: "I only know there is others states looking directly into the MIB file" is desired, because you are using the simple command line utilities from NET-SNMP project. The actual parsing in `mib.c` and `parse.c` https://github.com/net-snmp/net-snmp/blob/master/snmplib/mib.c should give you the information.

Comment: So, I have to parse the MIB. Well, I was expecting this anyway.
Thanks for giving the way to to that. It was use useful !

Comment: Any good toolkit will give you this info once the MIB is imported. Ours says %  ./oidinfo lgpEnvConfigTempControlAlgorithm
INFO  01/28.14:57:06 - NAME lgpEnvConfigTempControlAlgorithm = 1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.4.4.33
INFO  01/28.14:57:06 - MIB = liebert/LIEBERT-GP-ENVIRONMENTAL-MIB
parent = , subid = 33, name = lgpEnvConfigTempControlAlgorithm, access = 5
  type = 3
1, pi
2, pid
3, intelligent
4, proportional

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have any "good" toolkit. Any chance any of them is free ? I know of the paid ones....